# What does fork="true" do in nant script targets?

Tags: nant, fork

What is the difference between

```
<target name="target_fork" description="with fork" fork="true">
</target>
```

and

```
<target name="target_nofork" description="no fork">
</target>
```

I always thought it meant that the target would come back and continue execution when it calls other targets or external build files only if fork is true.  But some quick nant test scripts are not proving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

The property `fork=true` has no effect.

The term `fork` usually means that the code you run in a **task, not target** as you suggest, will execute in a different process (Virtual Machine in Java-lingo).

It is up to the implementer of a task, for instance NUnit in NAnt or the Java task in ANT, to define meaning of the `fork` property.

Comment: I usually fork a task if there is a risk that it can take down the process. If you run it in a fork it will not take down your "main" script.

I don't know about performance issues. Starting a new instance of a Virtual Machine usually means more resources.

Comment: I'm starting to think in terms of ant you are correct, but in terms of nant targets, fork does nothing at all http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/targets.html (although there seems to be a fork attribute on nant's nunit test element which runs test in a separate AppDomain): http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/nunit.html

Comment: Yes on the targets themselves fork does not make sense. But the meaning of fork can vary depending on the task interface. So I think your conclusion - Nothing - is correct.